# How to print and frame composite plaques for school pictures

Tags: printing

I have to provide a few plaques to a school. The previous plaques are printed on a relatively hard material/board and then framed (roughly 16x20) and hung on the walls of the school.

My work would be a composite layout (pictures of the students lined up in rows & columns) with the school name. What type of material do you think would work best?

I haven't been able to find a website that does this type of service.

1. I need to know whether I need to put the images in a template (composite column x row) layout if I find the service and
2. Are there any links to services or businesses that do this that I could check out that you are aware of?

Answer (score 1):

[bestcanvas.com](http://www.bestcanvas.com/format/) has several different options, I'm sure one of them suits your needs. You don't specify budget so I can't say too much about pricing.

I would recommend that you put the collage together yourself in Photoshop or any other application that lets you create the rows and columns you want. Then use the output of that for printing. Any printing service will help you when asked about their method of printing, desired file formats and similar.

A cheap alternative might be to simply print the photo file on a poster and then put that in a frame with hard back. This is generally what I do. There are any number of services online to do this for you. [shutterfly](http://www.shutterfly.com/info/16x20_digital_photo_print.jsp) is one example, googling the term "photo printing 16x20" will give you several more results on the first page alone.